# git - ignore files by timestamp

Tags: git, gitignore

My Situation is this:
I work on a modification for an old game with source code. There are a lot of files. Since it is an old game, all files that haven't been changed by me have an old file change timestamp.

It would be really helpful for me if I could only add the files to the repository (track them), that have been changed recently (by me). 
That way it would be really easy to see at once which files have been changed and it would make it easier to automatically package them.

I could write a program which tracks the timestamps of all files in the background and changes dynamically the gitignore file.
But is it possible to do such things with git onboard tools?

Greetings,

Neconspictor

Comment: With all files in git, it is really easy to see which files have been changed. Why do you want _not_ to track untouched files? If they don't change, they'll be there once and basically cause no trouble.

Comment: @Keldorn Because it would make it easier for packaging and it would be visible at once, what has been changed. And since there are lots of files, I feel it is just unnecessary to track them all. So, your suggestion is just to use git diff command and use the result as a base for further processing ?

Comment: Git can track large number of files, no problem. Very large (binary) files can be problematic, especially when they change often. What are we speaking about, giga-bytes or couple mega-bytes? Hundreds of files or tens of thousands?

Comment: Nice thing about tracking all is that you want to start tracking a file _before_ you modify it, precisely to track the modifications. (I may be wrong, but I suspect you have not much experience with git yet, and that this may be an instance of a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Keldorn : I'm certainly not a git guru, but I use it since 6 years now ;) I think that explicitely tracking changes after the first modification has been done would be helpful in my case. Therefore I asked whether it is possible using git. If not I think git diff should suffice for generating a list of modified files, that I can use for building a small tool for packaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a git tool to do this. The obvious location would be in the `gitignore` tool, but it only works with file patterns. You will have to generate this file list independently. Since your files are just local, the file list do not need to be pushed to the git server, so `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` sounds like the right location to put the list.

In your case, you can generate the list with something like (e.g. for 2015-03-22 at 15:30):

```sh
touch -t 201503221530 timestamp_file
find . ! -newer timestamp_file > .git/info/exclude
```

However, if not too troublesome I would generally advise to track everything in git:

- Unchanged files are not usually disturbing
- It is straightforward to get the list of changed files between commits (`git diff --name-only <sha1> <sha2>` or `git diff --name-only <sha1> HEAD`)
- Suppose you currently edited (thus track) only files A and B, then you start editing file C. You'll need to remember to add and commit file C *before* you start working on C in order to track future changes. Wouldn't it be easier to have C tracked already? (Here, there should be a way to use some [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), e.g. a `pre-commit` hook, to check that all files in `.git/info/exclude` are older than `timestamp_file`, and refuse the commit if that is not the case.)
- With this ABC example, when you want to get all *your* changes, you can't make a simple `git diff --name-only <sha1> HEAD` anymore, because it will include adding C before your changes. So it is in no way "easier to automatically package them", it is indeed much harder.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you're right and just storing everything in the repo is better. I will try out both and than I decide which to use.